# Can an employer terminate a contract prior to the start date?

Tags: termination, thailand

I signed a teaching assistant contract a month before the starting date and did processing government employment requirement with expenses. Two weeks before start of work, employer said to discontinue the contract which reasons not stated in the contract. So devastating to hear that I dont get the job and would be rare advertisement of school hiring since classes start in 2 weeks.

I felt depress loosing job when my capabilities not properly evaluated, when reasons were not in the contract, reasons that listened to feedback of co worker's who are not teacher, not evaluator, not by supervisor. Negative feedback also which are not my responsibilities but the main teacher's duties.

Is it ok for employer to discontinue the contract when employee expect to start and spent processing requirements and moved apartment, paid deposit due to employers advise?

Should employer pay the employee for terminating the contract?

Comment: It sounds like there was a dispute of some sort based on your question. Negative feedback could result in termination.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that if there are no protections for you spelled out in the contract it would be hard to force them to compensate you for your expenses.  However, you may want to contact a lawyer to see if they may be able to help you.

It may be helpful for others to answer if you add what country you are in.

Comment: thanks for answer, my work location in thailand

Comment: that seems like the right and only answer: talk to a lawyer